# Mevushal kol tzorko - what is it for meat?

Tags: shabbat, halacha-theory, food, melacha-creative-work, cooking-bishul

We poskin ([OH 318(4)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.318.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) that the law of cooking on Shabbos continues until solid food passes מאכל בן דרוסאי, and reaches מבושל כל צרכו - "completely cooked". What does "completely cooked" mean for meat? Is it "well-done" (my strong taste preference) or "rare" (as all the chefs seem to insist)? What evidence is there?
I have a problem either way:

- If rare is fully cooked, then Chazal's category מצטמק ויפה לו -
  "shrivels and gets better" would be describing the change from rare
  to well-done. I don't think I would describe that as "shriveling",
  i.e., it's *done* cooking but some of the water dries out.
- If only well-done is fully cooked, then rare was seemingly considered almost
  inedible (an intermediate stage between מאכל בן דרוסאי and fully
  edible). Even I probably wouldn't go that far. It cuts and chews
  fine.

Comment: You're thinking of cuts that we'd use for steaks (tender, low amounts of connective tissue). Most of the animal isn't like that (hence the price of steaks) and needs to be cooked for a long time to get it juicy and not tough. Brisket, for example, is commonly cooked for many many hours for a reason. (Not to mention most Jews nowadays never even see roasts from the back legs.)

Comment: "It cuts and chews fine." Chazal were well aware that some people ate even raw meat. See Menachot 11:7.

Comment: @DoubleAA It did occur to me that Chazal's description of שור הגדול (needs cooking all night and that's just barely enough) doesn't fit too well with my impression of today's butcher meat, which cooks faster than the potatoes. I think we breed and raise our cows to be mush.

Comment: IIRC is determined by the way the food is served most commonly by the person in question. Third cooked is calculated by the time it takes to reach the fully cooked state, divided by thirds.

Comment: @Chatzkel Need a source for all that.

Comment: @Chatzkel I think I do recall the Chazon Ish saying that the time for "third cooked" is (of course), once it starts cooking. It may take a while for the water to get hot, that doesn't count.

Comment: The Chazon Ish is in 37:6 https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14336&st=&pgnum=104

Comment: Thank you! I assume that the Chazon Ish gives that time measurement method because it's hard to think of what else to use. לולא מסתפיני I might have said that "half cooked" or "a third cooked" (Rashi says both) just mean, Somewhat cooked. You can eat it if you have to.

Comment: for what purpose are you asking? Is this about reheating food b/c of the general principal of ein bishul achar bishul? In the case of meat reheating meat would cause the fat to melt again which would still be cooking regardless of how well done the meat was cooked.

Comment: @Dude I don't think we poskin that way. As long as the liquid fat is absorbed in the meat instead of making a puddle, it would be fine. Besides, many poskim held that אין בישול אחר בישול applies to liquids as well. And there are other נפקא מינהs.

Comment: @DoubleAA So can I infer from your comment that you are answering that fully cooked means well-done, and rare used to indeed be almost inedible for most meat?

Comment: @MichoelR that was definitely true during the times of Chazal, but if the meat is *meant* to be served a certain way, then that level of "doneness" may be considered fully cooked. I heard "fully cooked" defined as "you would want to serve it to guests that way."

Comment: @Esther I only invite guests who like it well-done :) It sounds reasonable - but I would like to hear who discusses all this. I literally saw nothing at all up through the Mishnah Berurah. Just "partially cooked" and "fully cooked". Maybe Chazal had a simpler view of the world, and we're fancy.

Comment: The Gemara mentions raw meat as being edible in a pinch. If that was the determining factor in being half cooked, then it’s not clearly defined. It might even be 60% or so before one would eat it in a pinch. The machlokes over a third or half would also be irrelevant, since it’s all the same - edible in a pinch- call it whatever you want

Comment: Clearly the two gemaras (Kivsei Atzeres, ben Drusai) don't mean the same thing. In the first gemara, some special people (דעתן יפה) can choke the stuff down if that's the only way to fulfil the mitzvah of eating the korbon. The second gemara is about a robber who lives on the run, so he normally eats his meals when they aren't that great. He wasn't choking them down.

Comment: It's inconceivable to me that the shiur min haTorah for cooking is some random fraction. Chazal describe what happens when a malacha is done as "תיקון": it's "fixed". I assume that means that it went from inedible to edible, which is an understandable category. We just need to find out what determines that line, and what I (i.e., Chazal) meant when I said "edible" and "inedible".

Comment: The fraction isn't random at all.

Comment: I know it's not. The question is Why? What happens at that stage that represents a fundamental change?